# Is it fine to use has been + past participle of a verb

Tags: grammaticality, grammar

I know that **has/have been + verb -ing** makes present perfect continuous tense but here I am getting confused. If first question is grammatically correct, which tense is it in? Also, is it in passive form?

1)Has he been discharged from the hospital?

Is this question grammatically correct?

2)Is he discharged from the hospital?

Comment: Welcome to ELU. I invite you to visit the [ell.SE] StackExchange site, too, where answers are aimed at the needs of learners. (Many of us, both askers and answerers, are active on both sites.) Please take a look around both sites; and if you think ELL would be better for this question, you may delete it here and repost on ELL, or you may click on the *flag* link above and ask that a moderator migrate it.

Comment: You're confusing two different uses of the auxiliary _be_, one before present participles (the "progressive" construction), and another before past participles (the "passive" construction) that involves some noun phrase rearrangement. Both can be used with the auxiliary _have_ (the "perfect" construction -- isn't it amazing how many grammatical terms start with P?). And they can be used together, as well. See the [Verb Phrase Study Guide](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/VPguide.pdf) for details of all these constructions.

Comment: The question is better asked on ELL. 


Answer (score 2):

The first question is grammatically correct.  It is in the passive voice, and its tense is what's called the "perfect present".  That is, the question asks about an event that would have taken place prior to the moment of asking.

The second question is a little trickier. While I'm not sure whether the phrasing qualifies as grammatically correct, I can say that the more natural phrasing is "*Was* he discharged from the hospital?"

Semantically, there is very little difference between the two valid phrasings ("was he" versus "has he been").  It could be argued that the first phrasing indicates that the event would have occurred more recently.

Comment: Omno, why do you use "would have occurred" rather than "would be occurred", which, differently from the former, seems grammatically correct?

Comment: @Carlo_R. The phrasing "would be occurred" is not correct in Modern English.  There are two different constructions at work here: for a past participle "x" (so x could be, for example, "eaten" or "occurred"), we can say "be x" or "have x".  "Have x" is the present perfect construction, so "have eaten" means something similar to "ate".  "be x", on the other hand, indicates the passive voice. "You are about to be eaten" means that something will eat you, whereas "be occurred" has no obvious meaning.

Comment: @Carlo_R. _Would be occurred_ is ungrammatical, because _be_ +`PPart`is Passive, which applies only in transitive clauses; and _occur_ is obligatorily intransitive; like _happen_, it's just an inchoative -- change of state -- marker.

Comment: @Carlo_R. granted, this has not always been the case with the English, and there are still rare cases in which the copula ("to be") is used as an auxiliary verb, such as in the famous quotation of the the Bhagavad Gita: "Now I am become Death, the destroyer of worlds."  "Am" here is not ungrammatical, but functions much in the way that "have" would.

Comment: @John and Omno, thank you for these clear explanations.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: Thanks, I got the point now.
One more question - In your last comment, you quoted "Now I am become Death, the destroyer of worlds." Please explain a bit more about "am" here.

Comment: If you are learning English as a second language, I would advise you avoid this construction since it is archaic and sounds wrong to native ears. However, it used to be the case that (under certain circumstances) you could say "I am become" and mean the same thing as "I have become", which has a meaning similar to "I did become" or "I became". While this construction is no longer widely used in English, you see it often in related languages such as French and German.

Answer (score -1):

Your question shows that you're mixing up sentence tenses with sentence voices.  It's a bit complicated, but let me try to explain.

I have **done** ... - in this sentence, **to do** is the verb.  The tense is present perfect.

I have **been** ... - in this sentence, **to be** is the verb. The tense is also present perfect.

I have been **doing** ... - in this sentence, **to do** is the verb.  The tense is present perfect continuous.

I have been **being** ... - this sentence is extremely unlikely, but technically speaking, **to be** is the verb (being). Again, the tense is present perfect continuous.

All four of the above examples are in the active voice.  Simplified, this means the subject (the "I") is at the start of the sentence.  A couple more active sentences are:
"I ate the cake" (past simple) and "I have eaten the cake" (present perfect).

OK, so let's change the last two examples into passive voice.  We get: "The cake was eaten by me" (past simple) and "The cake has been eaten by me" (present perfect). By the way, the second sentence has the same tense as in your "Has he been discharged from the hospital?" example.
You'll notice there is no -ING after the word "been" here.  A passive sentence doesn't say "has been eatING", but rather "has been eatEN"!

So the -ING has nothing to do with a PASSIVE sentence in the present perfect, like "The cake has been eaten...".

The -ING is only in an ACTIVE sentence, and here are two more examples: "The cake has been eating..." and "He has been discharging...". Both of these are present perfect continous, and hopefully you'll never have to experience a cake that has been eating something or a person who has been discharging something in your life.

A little thing which might help is to ask yourself whether you're looking at a *verb* or an *adjective*.  The following examples cover active and passive voices, as well as present perfect and present perfect continous tenses: "She has been hungry since this morning", "She has eaten her lunch", "She has been eating snacks all day", "Her lunch has eaten her", "An anaconda has eaten her", "An anaconda has been eaten by her", "Her lunch has been finished".

If you can say which sentences are active and which are passive, as well as which are present perfect and which are present perfect continuous, and finally, if you can recognize which are verbs and which are adjectives, then you understand!

Comment: Thanks for explaining in depth. 
"She has eaten her lunch"-Present Perfect, Active
"She has been eating snacks all day"- Present Perfect Progressive, Active
"Her lunch has eaten her" - Present Perfect, Active
"An anaconda has eaten her" - Present Perfect, Active
"An anaconda has been eaten by her" - Present Perfect, Passive
"Her lunch has been finished" - Present Perfect, Passive

Is the sentence, "She has been hungry since this morning" in Present Perfect Progressive Tense(Active)? If it is, is it possible to use certain words without adding -ING in the Present Perfect Progressive Tense?

Comment: Tenses and voices *are* interdependent, you *do* mix-up though in a systematic way :)